# How to fill a matrix with the results of a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm currently writing a code which includes this `for` loop

```
for i = 1:17
    for j = 1:17
        if M(i,j,1) < d/2 && M(i,j,2) < d/2 && M(i,j,1) > -d/2 && M(i,j,2) > -d/2
            I = I0*(w0/w)^2*exp(-2*(M(i,j,1).^2 + M(i,j,2).^2)/w^2);           
        else 
             I = 0;      

         end
    end
end
```

where the `M` matrix contains `(x,y)` coordinates for each position `(i,j)`

Ex:

```
(x1,y1)  (x2,y1)  (x3,y1)
(x1,y2)  (x2,y2)  (x3,y2)
(x1,y3)  (x2,y3)  (x3,y3)
```

When I execute this code, I get a value for `I` for each combination of `i` and `j`, but I would like to put those result in a matrix.

How would you do that?

Comment: At this [link](http://www.mathworks.in/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), look for **Indexing Matrices with Two Subscripts**.

Comment: `I(i,j) = ....` but also look into preallocating memory in matlab. (basically you should go `I = zeros(17,17)` before your loops but google preallocation in Matlab to understand why, it's a pretty important concept for Matlab users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, do not use for loops:

```
I = I0*(w0/w)^2*exp(-2*(M(:,:,1).^2 + M(:,:,2).^2)/w^2);
mask = abs(M(:,:,1)) < d/2 & abs(M(:,:,2)) < d/2;
I(~mask) = 0;
```

Done!
Otherwise, `I(i,j)` will make it possible to store elements in a matrix. However, the above solution is recommended in terms of speed and clarity.

Comment: I was looking for a way to let go of my for loop, knowing this was really not the fastest way possible. And your method works absolutely fine, thank you a lot!!!